# Runtime exec sh does nothing

Tags: java, runtime, sh

So I want to execute sh script from java

Code:

```
String command = "/__data/1.sh";
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", command);
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not execute script");
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            p.getInputStream()));

    try {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(command + " says: " + line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading response");
    }
```

1.sh:

```
echo Hello
mkdir QWE
echo Hello2
```

What I got:

```
/__data/1.sh says: Hello
/__data/1.sh says: Hello2
```

Mkdir takes no effect

1.sh chmodded to 777

What's the problem?

UPD: oh, my fault, forgot the line, now edited. But the main question is why other commands do not work. Yea, like mkdir.
When I call /bin/bash -c /__data/1.sh from console it works propertly

UPD: oh, it seems, mkdir doesn't work propertly because I did not set full path. Sorry. Solved

Comment: What happens when you run `/bin/bash -c /__data/1.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `+ line` at the end of `println`. That should at least get rid of some of the confusion. Not sure why mkdir isn't working though.